# HTTPS page visible, but 404 in Firebug (and google)

Tags: apache, magento, ssl, https

We recently added HTTPS for this Magento shop:

https://www.weddingdeco.nl/

For some reason, we get a 404 not found in Firebug / WebInspector NET pane for the home page.

[image]

- A simple test page does not return a 404 :
  https://www.weddingdeco.nl/test.php
- Page seems to be working perfectly, also checked all css / js request, all 200 OK response.

Google insights also reports the 404 error

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.weddingdeco.nl%2F

Could this be something in the server configuration? Any ideas greatly appriciated

Apache config :

```
<VirtualHost 178.18.91.65:443 >
            SSLEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/wedding/dom              ains/weddingdeco.nl.cert
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/wedding/              domains/weddingdeco.nl.key
            SSLCACertificateFile /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/wedding/d              omains/weddingdeco.nl.cacert
            ServerName www.weddingdeco.nl
            ServerAlias www.weddingdeco.nl weddingdeco.nl  partydeco.nl www.              partydeco.nl
            ServerAdmin webmaster@weddingdeco.nl
            DocumentRoot /home/wedding/domains/weddingdeco.nl/private_html
            ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/wedding/domains/weddingdeco.nl/publi              c_html/cgi-bin/
            UseCanonicalName OFF
            <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
                    SuexecUserGroup wedding wedding
            </IfModule>
            <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
                    RMode config
                    RUidGid wedding wedding
                    RGroups apache access
            </IfModule>
            CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/weddingdeco.nl.bytes bytes
            CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/weddingdeco.nl.log combined
            ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domains/weddingdeco.nl.error.log
    <Directory /home/wedding/domains/weddingdeco.nl/private_html>
            php_admin_flag safe_mode OFF
            php_admin_flag engine ON
            php_admin_value sendmail_path '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f weddi              ng@weddingdeco.nl'
    </Directory>
```

Comment: I think it's problem with apache configuration, could you show configuration for this host?

Comment: See edit. Site is running on DirectAdmin, private_html is symlinked to public_html... Could it be something with Rewrites? Any ideas?